# Market Basket Analysis in R

Tags: r, market-basket-analysis

Given below are few observations from my data set

```
structure(list(p1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
    p2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), p3 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), p4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The column name depict a type of skill in a project required by 1 in front of that project row. I want to create a common basket of skills which occur together for maximum number of projects.
Is there any way of doing market basket analysis on the given data in R?
Or any way to solve the above problem.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `arules` package:

```
library(arules)
trans <-  as(as.matrix(df), "transactions")
rules <- apriori(trans, parameter = list(supp = 0.01, conf = 0.1, target = "rules", minlen=2))
inspect(sort(rules[1:5], by="confidence"))
#   lhs     rhs  support confidence      lift
# 1 {p1} => {p2}     0.2  0.5000000 1.0000000
# 2 {p1} => {p3}     0.2  0.5000000 0.7142857
# 3 {p2} => {p1}     0.2  0.4000000 1.0000000
# 4 {p1} => {p4}     0.1  0.2500000 0.4166667
# 5 {p4} => {p1}     0.1  0.1666667 0.4166667
```